# How to enable "ReST API" in mongodb-org version 4.4.4.1

Tags: mongodb, rest, pymongo

I am running `mongodb-org` edition `version 4.4.4-1` (pretty much the latest version, as of this writing).

I can't find where to enable it's `ReST API` interface. The `mongod(1)` start command does not accept the `--rest` option, as I've seen mentioned for either previous versions or other distributions of `mongodb`. And when I try the following in `/etc/mongod.conf` (also recommended for other versions):

```
net:
  http:
    enabled: true
    RESTInterfaceEnabled: true
```

`mongod` fails to start, complaining with `Unrecognized option: net.http.enabled` and `Unrecognized option: net.http.RESTInterfaceEnabled`.

Does anyone know how to enable the `ReST API` for this version?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That option hasn't existed since 3.6.

I tried to find this removal in release notes and couldn't.  But, the option is gone from source in the server 3.6.0 tree.

Comment: Thank you. For completeness, if you happen to know where they stated this, it would be good for your answer. Accepted and up-voted.